# How to use jQuery to add event listener and call function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using this line of code and think I'm receiving a type error because it's a jQuery object:

```
closebutton.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```

This should work for everything with the class stored in my `closebutton` variable. Is there a jQuery version of this I can use?

Comment: `closebutton.on("click", myFunc);` Assuming `closebutton` to be a jQuery obejct

Comment: search provider of your choice -> "jquery add event", [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case use the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.closeBtn', myFunc);

//$(parent).on('event', '.class', callbackfucntion);
```

Comment: I wouldn't answer questions for someone who is too lazy reading the documentation of jQuery or using Google.

Comment: By the way ... you have a Typo in your answer ... you close an extra bracket than you open .-) .... `$(document).on('click', '.closeBtn', myFunc);` should do the trickt !

Answer (score -1):

If the variable `closebutton` is a jQuery object you should use `on()` instead since `.addEventListener` is a javascript function and you can't call it on jQuery object :

```
closebutton.on("click", myFunc);
```

**NOTE :** Please read the jQuery official documentation about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ZakariaArcharki that's totally the case here: it's not useful to give someone the code snipped he could've gotten from Google within seconds without occupying other people

Comment: The right answer with explanation and the NOTE is useful for the author of question and encourage him to read the documentation.. and that point him to the right direction (And that finally why we're here)..

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `closebutton` is a jQuery object.

If it is a jQuery object, then you can add click listener simply like this:

```
closeButton.on('click', function() {...});
```

or

```
closebutton.click(function() {....});
```

or

```
closeButton.one('click', function() {...});
```

use `one` if you want the event handler to be only run once.